# XML Parsing Error in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Iam new to Phonegap, Iam not able to get the Response while Parsing the XML Url.what i have tried is,

```
function initLoginPage() {    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var urlString = "url/app/api.php?fn=employees";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processData;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", urlString, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}

function processData() {    
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
             document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                      
              } else{document.getElementById().innerHTML = "<b>Please Wait..</b>";}
}
```

I have called initLoginPage function when device is Ready.I have to show the Response in listView. iam using JQuery Mobile.The Response of Url is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<details>
<responsecode>200</responsecode>
<Employee>
<name>name</name>
<Fathername>fathename</Fathername>
<Address>address</Address>
<Number>12342456</Number>
<Enumber>4324421341234</Enumber>
<OfficeMail>test@gmail.com</OfficeMail>
<PersonalMail>test@gmail.com</PersonalMail>
<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
<DOB>21-06-1991</DOB>
<DOJ>05-03-2013</DOJ>
<PanNumber>123456</PanNumber>
<image>./images/1380372683.png</image>
</Employee>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have do mistake

```
  var urlString = url+"/app/api.php?fn=employees";
```

Comment: actually its complete url, i did not mention the domain address

Answer (score 0):

The variable xmlhttp is only defined in the scope of the initLoginPage function, so it isn't defined in processData.

There are two ways to solve your Problem. You use this instead of xmlhttp in processData:

```
function initLoginPage() {    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var urlString = "url/app/api.php?fn=employees";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processData;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", urlString, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}

function processData() {    
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;                      
   }
   else {
       document.getElementById().innerHTML = "<b>Please Wait..</b>";}
   }
}
```

Or pass processData as an anonymous function directly to xmlhttp.onreadystatechange:

```
function initLoginPage() {    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var urlString = "url/app/api.php?fn=employees";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {    
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;                      
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById().innerHTML = "<b>Please Wait..</b>";}
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", urlString, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```